# swig/c++ - why keep complaining undefined symbol

Tags: c++, swig

I am using SWIG 3.0.7.

I have the following simple c++ files:

```
myif.h

class If
{
    public:
        const std::string str() const;

        If(const char *str);

    private:
        std::string m_str;
};



myif.c

#include "myif.h"

const std::string
If::get_str() const
{
    return m_str;
}

If::If(const char *str)
{
    m_str = str;
}
```

Here is the swig interface file:

```
myif.i

%module myif

%{
    #include "myif.h"
%}

%include "stl.i"
%include "myif.h"
```

Here are the commands to build everything:

```
$PATH={swig_path}/bin swig -c++ -tcl myif.i
g++  -fPIC -c myif_wrap.cxx
g++ -shared myif_wrap.o -o myif_wrap.so
```

There is no error/warning. But inside tclsh when I load the library, I get the following error:

```
% load ./myif_wrap.so
couldn't load file "./myif_wrap.so": ./myif_wrap.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2If3strEv
```

Is it saying I need to link STL libraries? But not sure how to do that.

[EDIT] Yes, my bad, the function name is wrong, I should have made a caller C++ and made sure everything is fine in C++ before loading library in tclsh; also the module name in .i file needs to match the library name.

Comment: `const std::string str() const;` does not match `const std::string If::get_str() const`

Comment: You need to add `myif.o` to the shared library too.